# How to convert this xpath to css?

Tags: selenium, css-selectors, selenium-rc, selenium-webdriver

How to change this below Xpath to css? Please help.

```
//button[text()='Continue' and @class='buttonLargeAlt' and @type='submit']
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't.

The problem is that CSS selectors can't find by text. Therefore, you can't translate `text()='Continue'` XPath to a working CSS selector. This is one of the two main reasons for XPaths to be actually used till today for HTML elements selecting.

There was a [`:contains()`](https://www.google.com/search?q=css%20contains) pseudo class for this in CSS3, but it's long gone. Sizzle, the JS engine for CSS selecting in Selenium, has kept it, though. So if your browser doesn't support native CSS selecting (or you disable it), you can use it like this:

```
button.buttonLargeAlt:contains('Continue')[type='submit']
```

Comment: @Arran ...which uses Sizzle. Or, as a matter of fact, the jQuery team _wrote_ Sizzle. But yeah :).

Comment: +1 for "Unfortunately, you can't."  But FYI, Selenium does NOT use Sizzle in most cases, so you can't expect `:contains` to work unless you know exactly which browser versions it uses it for.

Answer (score 5):

I normally use this [cssify](http://cssify.appspot.com/), This is pretty cool

Comment: Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://us-central1-cssify.cloudfunctions.net/cssify?xpath=%2F%2F*%5B%40id%3D%22company-holding_table%22%5D%2Ftbody%2Ftr%2Ftd%5B1%5D%2Fdiv%2Fa%5B%40href%5D' from origin 'http://cssify.appspot.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.